# Does anyone know what font this is or can suggest something similar?

Tags: font-identification

I came across this on the internet. Does anyone know what font it is or, as the title says, suggest anything similar?

I dont mind learning a bit more photshop if needs be, as I think that's where I'm lacking:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned the letters and WhatTheFont is not giving any results, but a similar and free font is [Grobold](http://www.dafont.com/grobold.font?text=NON-LEAGUE&fpp=50):

[image]

Regarding the effects, the bottom blue word has a gradient from #248aca to #1e518a, and both lines have a black stroke. They can be added to any layer in Photoshop using Blending Options (right click on layer > Blending Options).

Comment: thanks very much yisela youve really helped me out. i will go give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This font is Bada Boom bb
Download the free Badaboom BB font by Blambot at FontRiver.com
http://www.fontriver.com/font/badaboom_bb/

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the font for comparison?